# AWS support Autoscaling for RDS PostgreSQL Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling

I have a AWS RDS Instance created with PostgreSQL. I would want to enable auto scaling in terms of CPU and RAM. Is that possible on PostgreSQL RDS Instance?

i have created a read replica and i cant see such option to enable the auto scaling. I have seen the option in Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL but not in standard RDS PostgreSQL.

Comment: Aurora has autoscaling, standard RDS does not.

Comment: @hephalump thanks for responding. Do you have any aws documentation url , if so could you pls share. i m searching for it.

Comment: You can technically roll your own “autoscaling” by deploying to multiple AZ’s and you can then add and/or remove as many replicas as you wanted, but this is not supported natively by AWS, and you’d have to build the logic. Why not just use Aurora if you need Autoscaling natively?

Comment: I think Amazon Aurora Auto-Scaling only adds/removed Read Replicas. To auto-scale the servers themselves, you could use [Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html).